# Class hierarchy problem with java generics

Tags: java, generics, extends

I have run into a problem with class hierarchy in a generic function.
I need to enforce that, with the two classes `T` and `U` specified in the function, one is the child of the other.
I have found to much surprise that the construct `<T extends U>` does not at all enforce a parent child relation of `U` and `T`.
Instead it also allows `T` and `U` to be the same type.

This creates a problem because it looks like in a case where `U extends T` Java will not indicate the error but instead it will happily deduce both objects to be of type `T` (which is true no doubt) and then compile and run the code without any complaint.

Here is an example that illustrates the issue:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      Bar bar = new Bar();

      // This code is written as intended
      System.out.println( justTesting(foo, bar) );

      // This line shouldn't even compile
      System.out.println( justTesting(bar, foo) );
    }
    
    static interface IF {
       String get(); 
    }
    
    static class Foo implements IF {
       public String get(){return "foo";} 
    }
    
    static class Bar extends Foo {
        public String get(){return "bar";}
        
    }
    
    static <G extends IF , H extends G> String justTesting(G g, H h) {
        if (h instanceof G)
            return h.get() + " (" + h.getClass() + ") is instance of " + g.getClass() + ". ";
        else
            return "it is the other way round!";
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
bar (class MyClass$Bar) is instance of class MyClass$Foo. 
foo (class MyClass$Foo) is instance of class MyClass$Bar.
```

I need to ensure that the parent child relation of the generic classes is observed by  the compiler. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: As a general note, due to type erasure, you *can't* use generic type variables in any runtime context, including `instanceof` checks, `new` calls, array allocations, etc. I'm honestly surprised `(h instanceof G)` compiles *at all*.

Comment: Interestingly there is a type check at compile time. The condition (g instanceof H) won't compile because it contradicts the inheritance hierarchy defined by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles, because `IF` is a "upper bound" for *both* `H` *and* `G`.

Means: Generics are not that "dynamic" as we think, and we could also write:

```java
static <G extends IF, H extends IF> ... // just pointing out that G *could* differ from H
```

---

Disregarding null check, is this, what you want:

```java
  static <G extends IF, H extends G> String justTesting(G g, H h) {
    if (g.getClass().isAssignableFrom(h.getClass())) {
      return h.get() + " (" + h.getClass() + ") is instance of " + g.getClass() + ". ";
    } else {
      return "it is the other way round!";
    }
  }
```

?

[`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

---

Prints:

```txt
bar (class com.example.test.generics.Main$Bar) is instance of class com.example.test.generics.Main$Foo. 
it is the other way round!
```

---

And watch out with "anonymous classes", e.g.:

```java
System.out.println(
  justTesting(
    new IF() {
      @Override
      public String get() {
        return "haha";
      }
    }, foo)
);

System.out.println(
  justTesting(
    foo, new IF() {
      @Override
      public String get() {
        return "haha";
      }
    }
  )
);
```

print both "it is the other way round!", so the decision here is not that "binary".

Comment: At that point, you may as well get rid of the generic bounds altogether and just take two `IF` as arguments, since they only serve to confuse and don't actually grant any type safety in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and even more for the solution of the problem via Class.isAssignableFrom(). I would have preferred a compile time check but having it at runtime is still ok.

Comment: I am not so sure about the 'lower bound' explanation. I had another example with no interface involved, just <G, G extends H> and it behaved the same. That's why I think is caused by the compiler's type deduction as I wrote in my original question.

Comment: i also tried: `<G, H extends G>` ... but the compiler doesn't "get it"... `System.out.println(justTesting(new Object(), "haha"));System.out.println(justTesting("haha", new Object()));` both work :))

Comment: `<G, H extends G>` is (for the compiler, obviously) analogous to `<G extends Object, H extends Object>` ...which also explains, why: `System.out.println(justTesting("haha", new Object()));` compiles(&runs)

Comment: and sorry it should be actually "upper bound" due to [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), but i picked up "lower bound", when tried un-compilable code. (just a matter of perspective ...i think ::)